# React SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

29.12.2022 UPDT:

When I visit all routes of initial nesting(such as `/` or `/company` or `/users` and so) my `bundle.js` comes from `/static/js/bundle.js`, it contains js and all is fine. But when I visit pages with more route nesting by entering it's url or refreshing page being on them it gives me error, cuz `bundle.js` now comes not from `/static/js/bundle.js` but for example from `/company/static/js/bundle.js` and it contains html. So error occurs

```
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    (anonymous function) (bundle.js:1)
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    (anonymous function) (vendors~main.chunk.js:1)
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    (anonymous function) (main.chunk.js:1)
```

So it seems like i have to change webpack configuration to give `/static/js/bundle.js` on every request no matter what nesting, but i can't get where i should change that

This is my `config-overrides.js` file:

```
const path = require("path");
// const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const { DefinePlugin } = require("webpack");
const rewireSvgSpriteLoader = require("react-app-rewired-svg-sprite-loader");
// const webpack = require("react-app-rewired");
// const { devServer } = require('react-app-rewired/config-overrides')

module.exports = {
   webpack: function override(config, env) {
      config.resolve = {
         ...config.resolve,
         alias: {
            ...config.alias,
            "@components": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components"),
            "@pages": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/pages"),
            "@hooks": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/hooks"),
            "@mock": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/mock"),
            "@scss": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/scss"),
            "@services": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/services"),
            "@store": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/store"),
            "@interfaces": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/types"),
            "@utils": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/utils"),
            "@ui": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/ui"),
            "@modals": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/modals"),
            "@assets": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets"),
            "@http": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/http"),
         },
      };
      config.module.rules = [
         ...config.module.rules,
         {
            test: /\.module\.scss$/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/components"),
            use: [
               {
                  loader: "sass-resources-loader",
                  options: {
                     resources: require("./src/scss/scss-resourses"),
                  },
               },
            ],
         },
      ];
      config = rewireSvgSpriteLoader(config, env);

      config.resolve.modules = [path.resolve("src")].concat(config.resolve.modules);
      config.output = {
         ...config.output,
         publicPath: "",
      };
      config.plugins = [
         ...config.plugins,
         new DefinePlugin({
            "process.env.URL": JSON.stringify(process.env.URl),
            "process.env.API_URL": JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL),
            "process.env.EDITOR_URL": JSON.stringify(process.env.EDITOR_URL),
         }),
      ];
      return config;
   },

   devServer: function(configFunction) {
      return function(proxy, allowedHost) {
         const config = configFunction(proxy, allowedHost)

         config.historyApiFallback.disableDotRule = true
         return config
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please remove the images and replace them with a text-based [mcve].

Comment: Please don't write in text-speak here. 'ofc' and 'idk' are not words.

Comment: Did one of your JS files `import` an html file?

Comment: @qrsngky so it turns up that yes, it imports an html file, but I did the same way previous programmer did but my reproduction causes errors

Comment: @evolutionxbox the problem really can be there?

Comment: @bluepuper Check the webpack config for rules that apply to html files. You may check if two different rules both match one file. Also be careful with `!!raw-loader!` kind of statements, or those "imports" where the extension can only be calculated during runtime instead of hard-coded.

Comment: @qrsngky I updated question and I think there is no webpack config or where it should locate in?

Comment: @bluepuper Could there there be something special in `config-overrides.js`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247921/discussion-between-bluepuper-and-qrsngky).

Comment: @qrsngky stack overflow recommended me continue in chat so what I did, I sent you my `config-override.js` file

Comment: If your cade is fine then you can run those command its work for me. first remove node-module then run `npm cache clear --f` then `npm install`. some time its occurs because of cache.

Comment: @MahmudulHasan unfortunately didn't help

Comment: You say "But when I visit pages with more route nesting by entering it's url it gives me white screen and error". On that page are you making any https or http query?. I guess you are getting html page from an http query where you excepct to get json data. Let me know if this is the case

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV what you mean by making http*? It's CRA just in case. You mean request to the server for some data? Can you please clarify it a little bit for me?

Comment: Are you using `JSON.parse` in your code where the error is happening

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV only for parse some inner data, like i got from the server string of array of images links and then just parse it and display images. Like this

Answer (score 2):

An SPA server should return the index.html for all paths that aren't real files, so it's understandable that you'd see a HTML page for an otherwise not-found path. This is so the SPA application can do routing itself.

Right now it looks like you're probably on `https://vgokna.ru/company/`, and that page attempts to load scripts from `.` instead of `/`, so `https://vgokna.ru/company/static/js/...` gets requested (and since it would otherwise 404, the server returns the `index.html` page). You'll need to make sure the HTML page attempts to load scripts (and other assets)  from the server root instead of the page's directory. IOW, if you'd have

```
<script src="static/js/bundle.js">
```

you'd need

```
<script src="/static/js/bundle.js">
```

instead.

Comment: But I don't have line where I link my script, my index.js file in `public` folder doesn't contain `<script src="">` or something

Answer (score 1):

I think the first screenshot is not your JS file, but an error message from the server. It's included as a JS file (in place of your JS script into your main HTML) and this cause the error what you see in the console.

It could be a response to a bad HTTP call with a bad URL in your script tag. I see a strange comment after "manifest" with a possible error message "only files inside the public(...)", but since I can't see the full response, I can't tell what the problem is.

If you can, please copy the entire server response to help me figure out what is the root cause!
If I had to guess it's a react router misconfiguration where your URL points out of your public folder.

Comment: oh it's really just html template, not my code ) Here it is

Comment: Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.

Comment: well, i just updated image in question

Comment: I think I understand that. The problem what I mentioned is your server is responding with this template to your request for boundle.js. As I can see the screenshot is in your dev tool which show us the server response for bundle.js request. The problem in this scenario what I wrote. Browser waiting for a JS but got a HTML and can't parse it because trying it like a JS where ">" character is not acceptable.
If I misunderstanding the bundle.js request and response (your screenshot) maybe you should clarify your setup. Codesandbox is a good way to show your problems.

Comment: In other words I understand it this is a HTML template but the problem is this template is in the server response to bundle.js request. Your browser waiting for a JS file but got a HTML. This is often a misconfigured router problem where the generated source for bundle.js file (in the main html which is not included here) is wrong and points a wrong url.

Comment: what is better to put into codesanbox to let you clarify the problem?

Comment: Yes, codesandbox would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in this lines in `config-overrides.js`

```
config.output = {
     ...config.output,
     publicPath: "",
};
```

I had to change public path because path of static files of js(`/static/bundle.js`) was conflicting with public path of react(/static/images/**.png etc), so i couldn't get js properly